# Creating AC magnetic field with DAQ card

Tags: power-supply, solenoid, magnetics, daq

I'm a second year student in electrical engineering. For my project, I am working with magnetic nanoparticles and I need to set up an AC magnetic field.

My plan is to build a solenoid (~1200 turns, 10 cm long, 4 cm diameter) and attach the solenoid to the power supply which is attached to the DAQ card. The NI-USB 2681 DAQ  has an analog output slot that can output a sine wave at 10 Vpp.

- Is this a correct way to go about doing this?
- What kind of power supply would you use?
- How would you accomplish this if you are to start with a DAQ card and a solenoid?
- Could you show a basic circuit diagram you would use?

The required current output to drive the solenoid is ~ 2 amperes, more or less, and the required frequency is 0.5-5kHz

Comment: "What kind of power supply would you use?": a cheap boombox or standalone audio amp (>50W) should be able to kick out 2A from 500Hz to 5kHz...

Comment: Amperes, not Arms. kHz, not kHZ. It looks like you are asking us to do your course final project for you. That's not how this site works.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Arms = amperes (root-mean-square). I suspect the correction is incorrect.

Comment: @user253751 That usage of the SI unit symbol with additional text is incorrect. See, for example, section 3.5.3.4 of IEEE/ASTM 10-2016, "American National Standard for Metric Practice".

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I guess I was having problem picking out parts I need to finish this project. (specifically, amplifier being compatible with the DAQ) as I have little-to-no hands on experiment with electrical equipment. Thanks for all the inputs though, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The frequency range of 500 Hz to 5 kHz, and the output current of 2 A, are both a perfect fit for a cheap, mid-powered, audio amplifier, at least to handle the power output part of the job.

If you want to control the magnetic field, then you will need to control the current, rather than the voltage, delivered to the coil. This can be done by putting a current monitoring resistor in series with the coil, 1Ω would be fine, and using an opamp to servo the input to the amplifier to match the output of your DAQ card to the voltage across the current monitor resistor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I will keep this in mind when setting up my magnetic field. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> My plan is to build a solenoid (~1200 turns, 10 cm long, 4 cm diameter) and attach the solenoid to the power supply which is attached to the DAQ card. The NI-USB 2681 DAQ has an analog output slot that can output a sine wave at 10 Vpp.

A power supply is designed to output DC, not sine waves.

If the frequency range is 500Hz to 5000Hz, use an audio amp as Neil_UK says. I wouldn't recommend class D if you want low noise.

If you want to add some DC bias, then you can't use an audio amp, because these are generally AC coupled. I would recommend picking a LM3886 amplifier board from your favorite online shop, and shorting the AC coupling capacitors at the input. Or just pick one of the many LM3886 PCB designs on the internet and make a PCB for it.

You will need a +/-15V power supply. The usual 2x30V 3A bench power supply you most likely have already in your lab will work fine.

Note LM3886 requires a gain of 10 to be stable, so if you use that gain, you will have to set your DAQ output voltage to +/-1V accordingly. If the module comes with a volume pot, it is better to replace it with fixed resistors, that way you know exactly what the gain is, and it won't change when someone fiddles with it.

If you want to set the magnetic field, then you need to set the current. You have two options for this:

1. Put a 1 ohm resistor in series with the coil, and acquire the voltage on it with your DAQ gear. This allows you to measure the current. Then you can simply adjust the output amplitude in software to get the current you want. You will also be able to measure other interesting things like the phase shift of your current, in case you need it.
2. Put a magnetic field sensor in your setup to measure the actual magnetic field. This would be a good idea anyway. Then acquire that, and adjust voltage accordingly to get the magnetic field you want.
3. Hack the feedback loop to make it a current-output amplifier. This is a bit more difficult and requires understanding how to make this sort of stuff stable, because the coil will add 90° phase shift, so a bit of compensation will be required. If you have never heard the words "Nyquist stability criteria", use the other option.

Comment: Wow, this answer is more than what I was looking for. Yeah, I don't understand the point 3, but I will definitely keep in mind as I will be working with solenoids and magnetic field for awhile, I think. Thank you so much!!!